# Bracket a string that's inside single quotes with percentage sign

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Until 4 years ago, I knew regular expressions at the back of my hand but I haven't touched them since so I need some help.

How would I compose a regex to replace all occurrences of `'whatever'` as `'%whatever%'`, including the single quotes?

I would like the following strings to convert as specified below:

```
Original                    Convert To
hello 'world'               hello '%world%'
'foo' bar                   '%foo%' bar
'foo bar'                   '%foo bar%'
foo 'bar' but gar 'har'     foo '%bar%' but gar '%har%'
```

Please note esp. the last example. I want *lazy* matches and *not greedy* ones. A greedy match in the last case would replace the original string with the value `foo`'%..%'`

I am using C#. The nearest I have come to for the first one is:

`Regex.Replace(s, "[Hh][Ee][Ll]{2}[Oo] '.*'", "[Hh][Ee][Ll]{2}[Oo] '%.*%'");`

But that's obviously incorrect. I don't know how to get back whatever was in the single quotes.

**UPDATE:**
Thank you all for your answers. They're all very helpful. I remember now looking at your answers. The thing I was missing was a *character entity reference* or something it was called where you could reference all your previous pattern matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to replace.

```
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"'([^']*)'", "'%$1%'");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/w4R8Aj)

Answer (score 3):

Search for `'([^']+)'` and replace with `'%$1%'`

Answer (score 1):

What about the following regex:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"'(.*?)'", "'%$1%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(')([^']+)\1
```

And use the replace string:

```
\1%\2%\1
```

Comment: Why all the capturing and backreference? It is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, you are right... but I posted the answer for doing this with another regex approach. I know that we can do that as JE SUIS CHARLIE pointed out, but mine is another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since the characters present inside the single quotes starts and ends with a word character, you could use the below lookaround based regex.

```
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<=')\b|\b(?=')", "%");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oD7aD8/2)